# Retrieve the last field in a string containing '/' as delimiter using tsch script

Tags: tcsh

I have writen a tcsh script. I have a file name and its path in a variable. For example : proj/debug/runs/filename
This path can be of any length. I need just the file name at the end. Is there any way to split this string and retrieve the file name?

Answer (score 0):

If your path is stored in a shell variable, say `$p`, then the `t` modifier will do what you want:

```
% set filepath = /one/two/thee/four
% echo $filepath:t
four
```

alternatively, you can use the `basename` command.